# Write text from EXCEL to text as a LIST using PYTHON or other programming method

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel files that contain values which i would like to write to text as shown on the right side of the image shown below. I have been doing this by hand but it is very tedious[image]. I have tried using python but I am getting frustrated with my accrued knowledge of python so far. Thanks for the help

for those that can't see it, I would like it outputted as this

```
[wind#]
Height=
Direction=
Velocity=
```

Comment: This is no can-you-write-me-a-programm forum. What have you tried? Where got you stuck?

Comment: I used python initally and tried R. But thanks for the heads up. I did not specifically ask for that. Just a guidance. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export your excel file to .csv (I hope you can figure out on how to do this on your own) file and get back something like this:

```
height,direction,speed
1,2,3
3,2,1
```

With the following .py script you can take the input file (which is in csv format) and transform it to your output. Where input.csv is your csv file which resides in the same folder as your script and output.txt is the file which will be your result.

```
f = open('input.csv', 'r')
g = open('output.txt', 'w')

# Header lines must be kept separately since we will be using them for every time
first_line = f.readline()
headers = first_line.split(',')
headers[-1] = headers[-1].strip()
length = len(headers)

# Capitalize each header word.
for i in range(length):
    headers[i] = headers[i].capitalize()


counter = 1
for line in f:
    values = line.split(',')
    values[-1] = values[-1].strip() #remove EOL character
    g.write('[Wind' + str(counter) + ']' + "\n")
    for i in range(length):
        g.write(headers[i] + "=" + values[i] + "\n")
    counter += 1

g.close()
f.close()
```

input:

```
height,direction,speed
1,2,3
3,2,1
```

output:

```
[Wind1]
Height=1
Direction=2
Speed=3
[Wind2]
Height=3
Direction=2
Speed=1
```

Comment: Haha I do know how to figure it out. The excel file is in the format .csv actually. But thank you. well appreciated.

Comment: I see where I was off in my code. correction has been made.